# load a page or video in to the dialog box

Tags: javascript

Helo,

Can you please explain the line in this code

```
 // Load rules in to modal 
    $('#rules .text').load('rules.html');
```

as i want to load a page or video in to the dialgue box.

Comment: No clue what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Load the rules.html into the element with id #rules with class .text

rules.html will be loaded from the server and the content is written into the element